# Using enumitem on a cheetsheet seems to cause -{}- to render as en-dash

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, enumitem

I'm using this [cheatsheet class](https://github.com/ACHinrichs/LaTeX-templates/tree/master/cheatsheet) to create a git cheatsheet.

I have a couple commands the are too long for a single line, so I added the `enumitem` package to use the `[style=unboxed]` to force lines to wrap. They now wrap, but `-{}-` now reduces to an en-dash instead of `--`

Reproducable by adding [cheatsheet.cls](https://github.com/ACHinrichs/LaTeX-templates/blob/master/cheatsheet/cheatsheet.cls)
to a ShareLatex project with the following document:

```
\documentclass[columns=3]{cheatsheet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\title{Test En-dash}
\author{ }
\date{March 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newcommand{\gitcmd}[2]{\item[\small\texttt{\$ #1}] \hfill \\ #2}

\section{Configuration}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\gitcmd{git config -{}-global user.name "<name>"}{Sets the name to be attached to your commits }
\gitcmd{git config -{}-global user.email "<email address>"}{Set to your email}
\end{description}

\section{Commit History}
\begin{description}%[style=unboxed]
\gitcmd{git log}{Display the version history of the current branch}
\gitcmd{git log -{}-oneline}{Display version history oneline summaries}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Toggling the `[style=unboxed]` comment on the two `descriptions` changes how `-{}-` is rendered. Adding a space between the dash and word (`-{}- global`) also works, but isn't a valid git command.

This appears to be a problem with `cheetsheet.cls`, as it does not occur if using the parent `article` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the label is unboxed, TeX no longer sees `{}`. Use

```
-{\kern0pt}-
```

Instead.

Comment: Thanks for this note! I'm having a little trouble understanding boxed vs. unboxed labels. Do you have a suggestion for where I should go to read up on this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for using my cheatsheet-class,

It seems to be an issue with `libertine`and `multicols`, and the `style=unboxed` parameter (Aside: What does this do?)

If you do not want to remove the `unboxed`, a workaround would be to change the Typewriter-Font to Computermodern, which does not seem to show this behaviour:

`\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}`